# How to open the list of a second selectbox after selecting the first selectbox in html using javascript?

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have two selectbox in html. Initially the first selectbox will show the list after clicking on it. After the selecting the first selectbox, it should open the second selectbox.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution which is given below.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select class="js-example-basic-single" id="mySelect2" name="state">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<input value="Open Select" type="button" onClick="$('#mySelect2').select2('open');" >
<script>
// In your Javascript (external .js resource or <script> tag)
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```